# SCLAertView waiting with API without duration

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use SCLAlertView waiting screen until the API call completed.
For example...

```
SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc]init];
[alert showWaiting];
[someAPIRequest makeAsynchronousCall:success^(MyClass *userData,NSError *error){
     [alert hideWaiting];

}];
```

But SCLAlertView automatically hide after a specific time interval but i want to hide by calling a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create `SCLAppearance` and override the values the values you would like to set.

Here is an example for **Swift 3.0**:

```
// Create the appearance
// Hide the close button and disable autoDismiss
 let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(showCloseButton: false, shouldAutoDismiss: false)
// Initialise the alert using appearance
let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
// Present the alert
alert.showWait("Title", subTitle: "Subtitle")
// 
someBlock {
   alert.hideView()
}
```

I guess creating it in **Objective C** should be no problem. However, i am only using SCLAlertView in a Swift project.